# Barclaycard ePDQ not hitting postback after migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

We recently migrated a site to a new server. This site integrates with Barclaycard ePDQ, and was working fine on the old server.

Since migrating, however, ePDQ is unable to hit our Postback Url (which is an ashx handler). They are seeing a response http code = -1, which we're told means it's either exceeding the maximum timeout (20 seconds) or the url simply can't be accessed.

We checked the firewall on the new server, and it is allowing incoming traffic over ports 80 and 443.

I am also able to mimic the POST with the same request data to the Postback Url using Fiddler, and this works fine. So no timeouts, and it is accepting POST requests over port 80.

The site was migrated several days ago, and running a DNS propagation tool against the domain shows it universally resolving to it's new IP.

We're running Windows server 2012  on the new server. The old server was running Windows 2008 R2.

Does anybody have any ideas why ePDQ is unable to hit our postback url?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Has their customer support confirmed the correct IP for the postback to completely rule out DNS propagation issues?

Comment: They have no way to confirm this apparently, which is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @user806982 Did you ever fix this? Am having this issue today?

Comment: @Callombert found some old support emails from epdq support and they said this error has been known for the following reasons:
• When your server takes over 20 seconds to respond to the ePDQ post sale request. ePDQ after 20 seconds will just move on and not listen out for the response.
• If the post sale URL cannot be reached at all for any reason such as a firewall is blocking the request.

Unfortunately I can't remember exactly how we resolved it - we ended up using an upgraded version of the platform soon after. Sorry I can't help further!

Comment: @user806982 Thanks, ended up setting up a relay on a separate server, epdq notifies another server which sends the POST data to the actual site. Ugly patch but edpq was absolutely hopeless, refusing to even simulate the post request and the code is so old there is no test environment for it. Advised client to switch gateway and hoping I never had to deal with them again.